# Template class to object file woes in c++ (GCC compiler)

Tags: c++, gcc, object-files

Okay, I have a situation like this.

foo.h

```
#ifndef _FOO
#define _FOO

template <typename ItemType>
class foo{
    private:
        //stuff
    public:
        //more stuff
};

#include "foo.cpp"

#endif
```

And of course, in foo.cpp, I have my implementation.  Assume that this class doesn't depend on including other files and whatnot.  Since c++ isn't cool with including header in source for templates without the compiler demanding explicit instantiation, we are including source in header.  Prof says no editing this code.  How do I get to my foo.o with GCC?  I can't find a way.

Comment: As far I know you should pass .cpp files by command line. To get object file use `-c` flag.

Comment: You don't need to make a `foo.o`. Just `#include "foo.h"` wherever you use `foo` and you should be good.